# Media Player on Android stops sounds all together

Tags: android, audio, media-player

I have seen alot of posts about it stopping sound early. This is not my problem. My problem is this... I have these 25 sounds up and working. When the phone is shaked it speaks, displays the text, and has an animation so the person looks like he is talking. It works just fine at first. The only way I was able to reproduce the problem that my client has found is by shaking it numerous times, then clicking back. Shaking back into it and shaking numerous times, then clicking back again. When I shake back into it again for a few times it works then suddenly all sound cuts out. Occasionally one will work but if back again and back in it usually stops making sound all together. Everything else functions as it should. Anyone encountered this before? Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class Ask extends Activity{
private SensorManager mSensorManager;
 private ShakeEventListener mSensorListener;
 String[] answer;
 int possibleAnswers, randomAnswer, talkRun=0, last=-1;
 int shake0;
 long lastClick;
 private MediaPlayer mp, sound0;
Context context;
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ask);
        Intent type = getIntent();
        lastClick = type.getLongExtra("lastClick", 0);
        context=this;

        final Random generator = new Random();

        possibleAnswers = 1;
        answer = new String[possibleAnswers];
        answer[0]="***Coughing***";



        //Sounds
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); 
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.askbud);
        mp.start();


        mSensorListener = new ShakeEventListener();
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

      final TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.answer);


        mSensorListener.setOnShakeListener(new ShakeEventListener.OnShakeListener() {

          public void onShake() {
              if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 900) {
                  lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();



                      randomAnswer = generator.nextInt(possibleAnswers);
                      if(last==randomAnswer)
                          randomAnswer = generator.nextInt(possibleAnswers);

                      animation();

                      if(randomAnswer==0){
                        if(shake0>=1){
                            sound0.reset();
                        }
                        shake0++;
                        sound0 = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.coughing);
                        try {
                            sound0.prepare();
                        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        sound0.start();
                      }

        });
    }





 @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(mSensorListener,
        mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onStop() {
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
    super.onStop();
  }
```

}

Just a slight addition to the problem. After I get the no sound to occur it continues to occur even after the app is closed and reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, this is a bit much to post in a comment, so here's what you need to do with setDataSource(). If you check the [docs for setDataSource()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource%28java.io.FileDescriptor%29), you'll see that it requires a `FileDescriptor`. You can acquire one for a Raw resource like so:

```
Resources res = getResources();
AssetFileDescriptor afd = res.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.coughing);
FileDescriptor fd = afd.getFileDescriptor();

//assuming existing MediaPlayer mp
mp.reset();
mp.setDataSource(fd);
mp.prepare();
mp.start();
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to do this. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: I must have done something wrong. I inputted that in each of the if(randomAnswer==) sections and no sound happened. It must have been the way I initialized mp. It's initialized the way it is above still. How should I go about initializing it? Not very experienced with MediaPlayer. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well just initialize one to begin with `MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer()`. It should then be in a state to accept a data source. I highly recommend THOROUGHLY reading the following link. If you can really understand that, the whole problem you're encountering will make a lot more sense to you: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#StateDiagram

Answer (score 0):

From your code,  it looks like you are creating MediaPlayer on click. But I dont see any code to stop / release it. So your application may be running out of resources, finally stopping additional media player content. That is why after couple of shake events, this issue is propping up.

Shash

Comment: Nah MediaPlayer is being created in onCreate and the assignments of sounds are in the onShake. So think if I put a sound0.stop() and so on in the onShake at the top that might fix the problem?

Comment: Stop as well as release the MediaPlayer

Comment: Where you're calling `sound0.reset()`, you should be calling `sound0.release()`. Alternatively (and this would be my preference), use `sound0.setDataSource()` instead of `sound0 = MediaPlayer.create()` and leave the `reset()` call as is. This will leave the MediaPlayer instantiated, but change the sound and prepare it for playback again.

Comment: @kcoppock Ok so I tried with the release and the problem still occurs. For the sound0.setDataSource() how do I have it call to the file? sound0.setDataSource(R.raw.coughing); doesn't work and I'm not sure what else would be placed in that.

Comment: Added an answer; too much to fit in a comment.